Reading from pointers with "no provenance" using asm consdered safe?
I recently wrote this rather simple asm function
#[inline(always)]
pub fn usize_raw_load_acquire(dst: &mut usize, src: *const usize) {
    use std::arch::asm;

    assert!(src.is_aligned());
    debug_assert!(!src.is_null());

    #[cfg(target_arch = "x86_64")]
    unsafe {
        // In x86, things are properly ordered by default, and these operations
        // are atomic!
        asm! {
            "mov rax, [{src}]",
            "mov [{dst}], rax",
            src = in(reg) src,
            dst = in(reg) dst,
            out("rax") _,
            options(nostack, preserves_flags),
        }
    }

    #[cfg(not(target_arch = "x86_64"))]
    compile_error!("unsupported arch");
}

What's interesting (maybe) is that I've marked it as safe...
Pointer reads are all sorts of scary for lots of reasons, but I can't see how any of these reasons apply here! Let's just focus on the provenancy parts though, and ignore my various other assertions about what this code does.
Essentially, I believe that src can be a pointer to anything... and be safely read in any environment (e.g. even if a &mut exists to the same object)
Why might I be wrong?

Even ignoring pointers to invalid addresses, assume you have a src_ref which is a &mut to the same address as src, if you do: *src_ref = 42; usize_raw_load_acquire (&mut dst, src); *src_ref = 0; the value in dst is undefined. In practice, there's a fair chance that it will be 42 in debug builds, and whatever was in src before this code in release builds. But that isn't guaranteed either, in theory anything could happen.

I struggle to see how reading a usize from a NonNull::dangling().as_ptr() would ever be called safe.


even if a &mut exists to the same object

This part is definitely wrong. Rust does not define the uniqueness of &mut references only within the Abstract Machine; it is defined also outside it - for example, FFI must also abide to them, and inline asm just as well.
In particular, the only defined thing about the aliasing rules is that they follow at least LLVM's noalias (even though they are stricter than that), and LLVM defines it as:

This indicates that memory locations accessed via pointer values based on the argument or return value are not also accessed, during the execution of the function, via pointer values not based on the argument or return value.

You can see it is defined in terms of memory accesses, not IR reads.
In the practical aspect, LLVM may optimize other code based on the assumption the value is not read (for example, overwrite the value stored), and this may break the other code and/or your code.
See also UCG#331 - Can inline assembly reads read uninit and violate noalias?.
The other invariants are probably okay. If you pass an invalid pointer, the processor will trap, but it is not within the Abstract Machine, so Rust does not make assumptions about it. It is like you call (via FFI) to a language that does not have UB.
